# Watch variable and change it

Tags: angularjs, watch

In AngularJS I have a directive that watches a scope variable. When the variable contains certain data then I need to alter that variable a bit. The problem is that when I change the variable that my `$watch` is triggered again. So I end up in a continuous loop.

```
scope.$watch('someVar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    scope.someVar = [Do something with someVar];
});
```

This keeps triggering `$watch` again, which makes sense. But I do need a way to change the watched variable. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: manage it using another boolean

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When a variable is watched for changes using `$scope.$watch`, angular checks if the reference has changed. If it has, then the `$watch` handler is executed to update the view.

If you plan on changing the scope variable within the $watch handler, it will trigger an infinite $digest loop because the scope variable reference changes every time that it is called.

The trick to getting around the infinite digest issue is to ***preserve*** the reference inside your `$watch` handler using *angular.copy* ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)):

```
scope.$watch('someVar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    var someVar = [Do something with someVar];

    // angular copy will preserve the reference of $scope.someVar
    // so it will not trigger another digest 
    angular.copy(someVar, $scope.someVar);

});
```

Note: This trick only works for object references.  It will not work with primitives.

In general, its not a good idea to update a `$watched` variable within its own `$watch` listener. However, sometimes it may be unavoidable.

Answer (score 17):

Inside function use  **if** condition to avoide continues for loop

```
scope.$watch('someVar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
   if(newValue!==oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    scope.someVar = [Do something with someVar];
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how dirty-checking works. Every time something on the `$scope` changes Angular will spin through everything that is attached to the scope and it will keep doing so untill there are no more changes.

If you want to do something like that, you will have to make sure that your `$watch` function is idempotent. You will have to look at both `newValue` and `oldValue` and figure out wether you've already applied the changes to your variable in this `$digest` loop. How you can do that depends a bit on what kind of changes you're doing to `someVar`.

Generally speaking, changing a watched variable in a watch-function is unfortunately not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

you can manage it using a bool variable

```
$scope.someVarChanged = false;

scope.$watch('someVar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    $scope.someVarChanged = !$scope.someVarChanged!;
    if($scope.someVarChanged) {            
        scope.someVar = [Do something with someVar];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can cancel it like this

```
var wathcer = scope.$watch('someVar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    scope.someVar = [Do something with someVar];

});
wathcer(); // clear the watch
```